# What does ${MAIN_ROOT} and ${BIN_DIR} means in bash under Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I find some code like below recently

```
python3 ${MAIN_ROOT}/pythonfile.py \
--value1=.....py
--value2=.....py
```

but it shows `[ERRON 2]:No such file or directory`
it seems `${MAIN_ROOT}`or`${BIN_DIR}` means some kind of file path, but I'm confused with it
Does someone tell me what it is or where I can find some information to know them?
Here is the part of file and original link [enter link description here](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleSpeech/tree/cf1a395e150b970c6ea2b60bd4162a68911adbee/examples/aishell3/vc1)

```
#!/bin/bash
stage=0
stop_stage=100

config_path=$1
ge2e_ckpt_path=$2

# gen speaker embedding
if [ ${stage} -le 0 ] && [ ${stop_stage} -ge 0 ]; then
python3 ${MAIN_ROOT}/paddlespeech/vector/exps/ge2e/inference.py \
    --input=~/datasets/data_aishell3/train/wav/ \
    --output=dump/embed \
    --checkpoint_path=${ge2e_ckpt_path}
fi

# copy from tts3/preprocess
if [ ${stage} -le 1 ] && [ ${stop_stage} -ge 1 ]; then
# get durations from MFA's result
echo "Generate durations.txt from MFA results ..."
python3 ${MAIN_ROOT}/utils/gen_duration_from_textgrid.py \
    --inputdir=./aishell3_alignment_tone \
    --output durations.txt \
    --config=${config_path}
fi

if [ ${stage} -le 2 ] && [ ${stop_stage} -ge 2 ]; then
# extract features
echo "Extract features ..."
python3 ${BIN_DIR}/preprocess.py \
    --dataset=aishell3 \
    --rootdir=~/datasets/data_aishell3/ \
    --dumpdir=dump \
    --dur-file=durations.txt \
    --config=${config_path} \
    --num-cpu=20 \
    --cut-sil=True \
    --spk_emb_dir=dump/embed
fi
```

Comment: Seems like environment variables in some bash script or build file. Can you attach the code? What file?

Comment: The command line is interpreted by the shell, not by Python

Comment: Sure, I edit part of it above. Briefly it is a shell command by typing `./Processor.py` and then the inside code will be excuted but it always can not find the files at `python3 ${BIN_DIR}/preprocess.py \` and `python3 ${MAIN_ROOT}/utils/gen_duration_from_textgrid.py \` . So I want to know where is the $MAIN_ROOT and $BIN_DIR to excute

Answer (score 0):

These are [environment variables](https://opensource.com/article/19/8/what-are-environment-variables) that you need to export yourself before running their code. The repository you linked to provides several examples of usage of their project, which export this variable. See for example `examples/librispeech/asr2/path.sh`, which is:

```sh
export MAIN_ROOT=`realpath ${PWD}/../../../`

export PATH=${MAIN_ROOT}:${MAIN_ROOT}/tools/sctk/bin:${MAIN_ROOT}/utils:${PWD}/utils:${PATH}
export LC_ALL=C

export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
# Use UTF-8 in Python to avoid UnicodeDecodeError when LC_ALL=C
export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
export PYTHONPATH=${MAIN_ROOT}:${PYTHONPATH}

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/lib/


MODEL=u2_kaldi
export BIN_DIR=${MAIN_ROOT}/paddlespeech/s2t/exps/${MODEL}/bin

LM_MODEL=transformer
export LM_BIN_DIR=${MAIN_ROOT}/paddlespeech/s2t/exps/lm/${LM_MODEL}/bin


# srilm
export LIBLBFGS=${MAIN_ROOT}/tools/liblbfgs-1.10
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:-}:${LIBLBFGS}/lib/.libs
export SRILM=${MAIN_ROOT}/tools/srilm
export PATH=${PATH}:${SRILM}/bin:${SRILM}/bin/i686-m64

# Kaldi
export KALDI_ROOT=${MAIN_ROOT}/tools/kaldi
[ -f $KALDI_ROOT/tools/env.sh ] && . $KALDI_ROOT/tools/env.sh
export PATH=$PWD/utils/:$KALDI_ROOT/tools/openfst/bin:$PWD:$PATH
[ ! -f $KALDI_ROOT/tools/config/common_path.sh ] && echo >&2 "The standard file $KALDI_ROOT/tools/config/common_path.sh is not present, can not using Kaldi!"
[ -f $KALDI_ROOT/tools/config/common_path.sh ] && . $KALDI_ROOT/tools/config/common_path.sh
```

which exports both `MAIN_ROOT` and `BIN_DIR`.